# DateFactory good pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have two log files which I feed with data, obviously.

Every entry in each log file should include date and time when an event occurred.

For instance:

```
06/05/2015 17:10:00 new connection established
```

**How do I retrieve the date?**

```
SimpleDateFormat sFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
sFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Now currently two different classes (threads) need the current date and time.

Due to that I don't want to write in every class a method which returns `sFormat.format(cal.getTime())` because it is unprofessional, I thought about a `DateFactory.class` :

```
public class DateFactory {
    public static String datePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    
    public static String retrieveDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
        
        return simpleFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

And now I am able to retrieve the current Date within my whole project no matter how much threads will join my project.

Do look like this:

```
out.write(DateFactory.retrieveDate() + " " + newConnection.getInetAddress() + " " + " new connection established" + TheServerSocket.newLine);
```

Where `out` is a instance of `FileWriter.class` if this is relevant for someone.

**The Question:**

Do I totally miss something and my idea is the worst on planet?
Are there any disadvantages in using my `DateFactory-solution` compared to a totally different design pattern (if there is any) which I may be completely unaware of? Or are there general any disadvantages in using my `DateFactory-solution`?

Comment: Have you considered using existing logging solutions? They all include such functionality.

Comment: @user3707125 No! Can you give more detail what logging solutions you mean?

Comment: Designing such a utility class isn't the worst idea on the planet. If you encounter the same code multiple times, this is good reuse. But in your case you won't need to include it in your log entries, as almost every logging framework does include a timestamp by default. If not, it can be configured to do so. (even java.util.logging does it.)

Comment: Try logback over slf4j. http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html

Comment: You guys caught me at what I do often, reinventing the wheel. It is really annoying to me that I wrote such a long question to hit on already existing logging features......... But anyway, thanks I will have a closer look on these logging solutions.